# Java application only playing selected videos in my computer but not in another's

Tags: netbeans, vlc, libvlc

I recently developed a software (intended for Desktop applications) using the Swing tools of Netbeans. The challenge I am having is that my application works as expected only on my PC. When a particular button is pressed a corresponding video is played (using vlc).

However, when I distribute the application (having used launch4j to convert from .jar to .exe) to other PCs the video portion does not play. I know it is because I specified where the video is located in my PC. But I want to learn how to do it differently - to make it play in other PCs. Below is the code that I am currently using to play specific videos (without using JChooser). 
I also tried using file paths to be able to locate the absolute file paths of the respective files. The pressing challenge, though, is the generated single backward slash instead of double slashes. This is preventing me from using the self-generated file paths. Can I sort the letters and add an extra slash every time each single flash appear. Then afterward combine this and generate  the file paths? What do you suggest can be done?

The code section:

```
    try{
ProcessBuilder pbh = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VLC\\vlc.exe", "C:\\Users\\INJESUSNAME\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\GESVI_1_1\\dist\\JECE\\GVI National Anthem.mp3");

    pbh.start();
}

    catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

//Second attempt
    import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;

     //Get VLC's absolute path
    File check_vlc = new File("vlc.exe");
    String absolute_vlc_path = 
    check_vlc.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("absolute_vlc_path" 
    +absolute_vlc_path);

    //Get user_mp3's absolute path
    File check_user_mp3 = new 
    File("User_Anthem__2_.mp3");
    String absolute_ check_user_mp3 _path = 
    check_user_mp3.getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("absolute_ check_user_mp3 
    _path " + absolute_ check_user_mp3 _path);
    ProcessBuilder pbh;
    pbh = new ProcessBuilder(absolute_ 
    check_user_mp3 _path, absolute_vlc_path);
    pbh.start();
```

Comment: Check if vlc.exe is installed in the same folder as on your PC and of course if the .mp3 is in the same location.

Comment: Yes I later ensured that they (vlc.exe and the .mp3) were in the same location. This was at the stage of converting the file for distribution purposes. The challenge, however, is that the application does not play the videos when using other PCs. Is there a way I could get the code to unilaterally locate the video file (this will be in the dist folder) when being used in another PC? Thanks so much for your leading suggestion. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You should run your programm with command line arguments.

E.g. java -jar VLCPlayer.jar path_to_your_vlc.exe start_path_to_your_mp3

This code iterates over a start folder recursivly and adds the files to an array. You could list this array to the user interface.

```
public class VLCPlayer {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length>=2) {
            String vlcplayer = args[0];
            String mediafolder = args[1];
            ArrayList<File> files = getPaths(new File(mediafolder),
                new ArrayList<File>());
            if(files == null) return;
            try {
               for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++)
                  System.out.println(files.get(i).getCanonicalPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }      
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<File> getPaths(File file, ArrayList<File> list) {
        if (file == null || list == null || !file.isDirectory())
            return null;
        File[] fileArr = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : fileArr) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                getPaths(f, list);
            }
            // check, if it is vlc playable file (e.g. mp3)
            list.add(f);
        }
        return list;
    } 

}
```

Comment: To test it in Netbeans you can enter the arguments in the properties->run->arguments.

Comment: I celebrate your decision to help out. Is using this code not going to require the user (in this case age 4 user) to make inputs? I wanted it such that the only requirement from the user is to voluntarily click a button of interest and the corresponding video will play. That was why I used the exact file path which only now works on my PC but cannot work on another PC because I needed to change the file path. I want to avoid this requirement. Please what do you suggest should be done to make respective videos playable on any PC whenever a button is pressed? Thanks for your leading comments.

Comment: Okay, in this case my code doesn't fit your requirements and leads to an completely other solution. I think you have to offer an user interface that shows a list of playable files for vlc. This isn't a quick'n'dirty solution for stack overflow. 
My suggestion: Give the vlc path and the path to your media files as arguments to the Java program. List your media files in the user interface with a play button for each media. I hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers for your swift and effectual responses. That (listing of paths - vlc's and media's) is the challenge I really wish to solve. For presently each file path links to my current PC but it won't be feasible nor usable in another PC because of the obvious difference (e.g. names of leading folders of other PCs). That was why I crave a suggestion that would enable the program to by itself search for and use the respective files whenever a corresponding button is pressed on the UI.

Comment: I updated my answer. The code fills an array with files from a starting folder, that is being processed recursivly. You can then make this list available to your user interface.

Comment: That is quite an interesting solution. But won't the starting folder require referencing (thus leading to the same file path challenge that I wish to resolve once and for all)? Each button has a picture that explains what it represents. So just clicking on the button implies that the user want to watch it. In other words, one button represents one video. Thanks

Comment: This solution implies, that all Media files are in subfolders and sub subfolders of your root folder, you specify. If you start with c:\ then your whole harddisc is crawled. Not the best start point.

Comment: Thanks for the usual leading comments. I just updated my question. Can you look at it and suggest another way forward?